# Command line syntax for launching a softphone

Tags: command-line, windows-registry, regedit, softphone

I was advised to use the following command, from the Windows command line, in order to get my softphone to dial a number:

```
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\qutecom\\qutecom.exe\" \"-c\" \"call\\%1\""
```

However, when I use that command, I get an error saying "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. I am sure that the path is correct.

I was also told to use the command below:

```
"c:\program files\qutecom\qutecom.exe" -c call\%1
```

When I use this command, the softphone opens, but doesn't dial.

The documented command for the softphone is `qutecom -c call\123456`. Can someone help me get the syntax right? I am unfamiliar with editing the registry. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using is correct and works for me:

[image: Qutecom command line dialing]

The version installed is 2.2 on a Windows 7 x64 machine.  Trying a re-install might help, but there is a unresolved [bug](http://trac.qutecom.org/ticket/176) where dialing from the command line doesn't seem to work.  Perhaps try a different SIP client, or a different machine for testing.

Comment: I got it working for a few calls by adding a few apostrophes, but then it stopped. Now, it seems like the browser is passing "tell:" along with the number. I tried tel:1111111111 in Firefox and Explorer and each has the same problem. The error message it gives is user/number not found tel:+1111111111. If I issue the command from the command line, QuteCom dials the number just fine. Thanks for your help. It looks like it will be another day of fiddling for me.

Comment: If it is passing the URI (tel:) through with the number, then I would consider using a batch file as the target for the registry command, and have that batch file strip off the tel: and pass the number to qutecom (this also means that if you change SIP clients, you just edit the batch file, rather than the registry)

Comment: It sems to be the % that is causing the problem. If I take the %1 off and replace it with a +, it passes 001, without the tell:+. I've tried a bunch of different combinations, but there doesn't seem to be a way to di it without the %. I don't know how to make a batch file. I guess I'll try to figure out. Thanks for the help.